# How do I query for paths in spring data neo4j 4?

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

In an earlier version of spring data neo4j (3.3.1), I was able to query for paths in my database and return them as `Iterable<EntityPath<S,E>>` like this:

```
public interface ArgumentNodeRepository extends GraphRepository<ArgumentNode> {
    @Query("START t=node({0}), r=node({1}) MATCH p=t<-[:SUPPORTED_BY|INTERPRETS*0..]-r RETURN p")
    Iterable<EntityPath<ArgumentNode, ArgumentNode>> getPaths(long childId, long rootId);
}
```

I'm trying to migrate to 4.0.0 and the EntityPath class seems to have disappeared. I don't see any mention of EntityPath in the [migration guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#migration). What's my new return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EntityPath isn't supported in SDN 4, but you can still query for paths.
I have an example [here](https://github.com/luanne/flavorwocky/blob/sdn/src/main/java/com/flavorwocky/repository/IngredientRepository.java#L20) which contains a Cypher query that returns a path- the return type is `Iterable<Map<String, Object>>`

This represents a collection of paths, each path containing a list of interleaved nodes and relationships in the path (nodes and relationships represented as a Map). An example of how I processed the path is https://github.com/luanne/flavorwocky/blob/sdn/src/main/java/com/flavorwocky/service/PairingServiceImpl.java#L57

Comment: For a similar query, I used to return `List<Object>` but when I only changed the return type to `Iterable<Map<String, Object>>` it returned much more information ! What other types can I return to have different details of results ? Would reference a document please ?

Comment: this worked for me. @luanne going through your github project was very help to deal with paths in neo4j with java. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also Neo4jOperations for this. 
Just create a custom repository implementation (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations), and call the Neo4jOperations bean from there:

```
neo4jOperations.queryForObjects(ArgumentNode.class, "START t=node({0}), r=node({1}) MATCH p=t<-[:SUPPORTED_BY|INTERPRETS*0..]-r RETURN p")
```

This will return a list of ArgumentNodes