# sdn4.0 set resultDataContents graph

Tags: d3.js, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I want to use SDN4.0 to visualize by D3 in web application.For example,I want to use the following cypher query to get data:

```
   @Query("MATCH  (n:app)-[r:r1]->(m:app) RETURN n.alias,r,m.alias")
   Iterable<Map<String, Object>> getAllRelations();
```

But the httpServer not response the exact data I want.

```
[{n.alias=A, r=(227)-[r1]->(235), m.alias=B}, ....]
```

And I want to response `r1`'s properties ,tried `r1.*` but failed.

From the http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/ there is possible to set resultDataContents to `graph`(origin as `rest`)

So Is it any possiblity to set this parameter in SDN4.0 or have other solutions?

Thanks if having any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do I query for relationship data in spring data neo4j 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075364/how-do-i-query-for-relationship-data-in-spring-data-neo4j-4#33093920)

Above Answer solved my question.By using `Neo4jOperations.queryForObjects()`  under Spring data Neo4j and return path in cypher query.

Answer (score 0):

SDN is for creating domain rich applications. As such it's not the best tool to use if all you need is a list of properties to represent a graph.

You have a couple of paths as I can see it:

- Model your application properly with SDN. Use `@NodeEntity` on a class called `App` and create a `@Relationship` to another `App`. You can then leverage SDN's repositories to return you a rich domain model which you can then transform (e.g. using DTO's) to the front end if need be.
- Use the [java Neo4j client](https://github.com/inner-loop/java-neo4j-client), [OGM HTTP driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-ogm-http-driver) (Undocumented), or if you are happy to completely use Javascript (either from the browser or with meteor or using a NodeJS server) you can just use the [Javascript driver](https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/) and call the database directly.

Either way if you are using D3 I highly recommend you use [JSOG](https://github.com/jsog/jsog-jackson) to represent your model in the front end.

Comment: I had little understanding of PATH1 you mentioned above. Between 'App' need to relate a rich relationship(have properties).So @Relationship not satisfied to the need.So now I want to use EmbeddedDriver to provide data for visualizing by D3.Thank you